# Making nouns from present perfect

Tags: nouns

How to make noun from present perfect form? I mean we can make noun from present simple by adding –**ing**:

teach (a verb) -> teaching (can be used as a noun):

> *I like his way of teaching.*

Is it possible to add –**ing** to the end of present perfect to make noun? For example, is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> *Having been tired of trying, he wants to give up*.

or

> *having bankrupted, We were disappointed*.

Comment: The only way to "make a noun" from a verb in English, is to add ing to the bare infinitive. By the way, we say: to go bankrupt. But: /having gone bankrupt/ is not a noun. It is a verbal phrase. "Being tired of trying, he just gave up." being tired of=as he was tired of //more usual.

Comment: @Lambie: "The only way to "make a noun" from a verb in English, is to add ing to the bare infinitive" //////// Is it really the "only way" to nounise verbs in English?

Comment: @Wistful Ditto. Nominalization of verbs takes many forms. _Nominalization_ itself is a noun nominalized from a verb. _To nominalize_ means more than adding -ing to the bare infinitive of a verb.

Comment: Yes, nouns can be formed from the _ing_ form of verbs, as in "I witnessed the **killing** of the seals". "Kim was involved in the **writing** of the letters". These are **not** formed from the base forms, but directly from the gerund-participle _ing_ verb forms. Note that in your example "having" is a verb, not a noun.

Comment: @EddieKal Excuse me, but nominalization means the use of a word that is not a noun as a noun. BUT: there is only one way to *create a noun from a verb* and that is by adding ing to the bare infinitive, sometimes doubling the end consonant or dropping a vowel: stop, stopping, arrive, arriving, leave, leaving, get, getting, fly, flying.

Comment: @BillJ The actual formation is based on the bare infinitive. *They are  not formed from the gerund*. The gerund can be used **as the noun**. **The gerund is already a noun**. And that is the ONLY way to get a noun from a verb in English. Some require doubling the consonant, others dropping a vowel.

Comment: @Lambie No it isn't. Conversion involves the changing of a word's syntactic category without any concomitant change of form. Thus in my example the gerund-participle verb "killing" becomes the noun "killing" by conversion.

Comment: @BillJ "These are not formed from the base forms, but directly from the gerund-participle ing verb forms." No, the gerund-participle changes its function not its form.

Comment: @Lambie No it doesn't. Conversion, by definition, means there is no change of form. I suspect you're thing of inflectional morphology, not lexical word formation. And function has nothing to do with it, Verb and noun are not functions, but word categories (POS). Functions are subject, object, complement etc.

Comment: @BillJ Unbelievable. Really.  Every single thing in an utterance or sentence **serves a function**.  Verbs and nouns **serve a function in utterances or sentences. Geesus.

Comment: Go look up lexical word formation by **conversion**, e.g. the gerund-participle verb "killing" ~ the noun "killing". That's how the noun is formed.

Comment: @shapoor Are you clear now about the two major facts: 1. gerunds (_ing_ forms) are verbs, not nouns. 2. the _ing_ noun form derives not from the base form, but by conversion from the _ing_ verb form. Thus in, for example "He witnessed the killing of the birds", "killing" is a noun formed by conversion from the gerund-participle verb "killing", not from the base form "kill".

Comment: @BillJ
 Yes, thank you and all other people who participated in this discussion.

Comment: @shapoor The crucial point (that some others can't grasp) about conversion is that it is not the lexical base of the verb that is converted but an inflected form. Thus the formation of nouns like "killing" in my example, and "teaching" in yours is not from the base forms "kill / teach", but from the gerund-participle verbs "killing / teaching". Thus we have homonymous pairs of words of different primary categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are confusing tense with participle. The present simple is a verb form in accordance with the present simple tense in English. It is *not* the same as the unmodified base verb form, not even in its formation. The unmodified form is the bare infinitive of a verb, but the present simple is often not. For exmaple a third person singular subject will conjugate the verb "eat" to "eats" in the present simple.

Second, you are confusing two similar but distinct concepts in English: **gerund** and **present participle**. A gerund is a verb form that allows the verb to function as a noun, and a present participle of a verb is a form that allows the verb to function as an adjective, adverbial, or a tense marker in conjunction with an auxiliary verb. In English these two simply happen to share the same form.

With technicalities out of the way let's look at your sentences.

> I like his way of teaching.

"Teaching" here is a gerund--a verb used as a noun. You know this because you can replace it with a noun.

> I like his way of meditation.

> Having been tired of trying, he wants to give up.

Here "trying" is a gerund, but "having" is not. It is the present participle of "have" leading a participial phrase "having been tried of trying". The present participial modifies the subject of the sentence "he". "He" *has been tired of trying*. The same goes for your next sentence:

> Having *gone* bankrupt, we were disappointed.

Note it is "go bankrupt" and "we" should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

> Having been tired of trying, he wants to give up.

This is formed correctly - but *having been tired of trying* I believe is participial phrase - the phrase modifies *he wants to give up* like an adjective or adverb.

> present perfect form

Verbals (which include infinitives, gerunds, and participles) don't have tenses - so technically they can't be past or present.  But you can use *have* to express a perfect infinitive, gerund, or participle.

Gerund:

> I have gone to the park today.

> Having gone to the park is something I have done today.

Infinitive:

> I want to go by the park today.

> I want to have gone by the park before she gets home.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorting out the present perfect, participial phrases, gerund nouns and gerund phrases.**

The present perfect is this:

A - He has taught for many years.
B - We have learned how to read Hindi.

**The present perfect is have + a past participle (third person s or es)** as can be seen above and below:

- have been
- have seen
- have walked.

**You can see that you cannot add ing to those two sentences (A and B).**

Now, let's look at the type of verbal phrase you are trying to use **based on A and B:**

A - **Having taught** for many years, he decided to leave the profession.

B - **Having learned** to read Hindi, we were now able to read many new authors.

**Those are called participial phrasea**.

> **Participial Phrases are present participles or past participles and any modifiers, objects, or complements. Participial phrases contain
> verbs which act as adjectives in a sentence.**

[participial phrases](http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/verbals/#:%7E:text=Gerund%20Phrases%20contain%20verbs%20ending,the%20object%20of%20a%20preposition.)

**Your examples are similar to those in that they use participial phrases:**

- Having been tired of trying, he wants to give up. [See corrections below]
- **Having become tired of trying**, he wanted to give up. [past participial phrase]
  OR
- **Being tired of trying, he wants to give up**. [present participial phrase]

Please note: We would often use: *as he became tired* and *as he is tired*, as those participial phrases are somewhat heavy, though they can be very useful at times.

Finally, your question is really *about transforming a present perfect into a participial phrase and not a noun.*

In: /I like his way of **teaching**./, **teaching** is a noun, called a noun gerund or gerund. Of course, it is also a verb: I am not teaching this afternoon.

You can form nouns from any verb by adding ing, and sometimes you have to double the consonant (stop, stopping) or drop a vowel (leave, leaving). However, that was not the actual issue brought up in the question's examples.

Finally, there are gerund phrases that can be used as the subject of a sentence:

- **Having eczema** is no fun.
- **Having been a thief** was his burden to bear.

> A gerund phrase is a phrase consisting of a gerund and any modifiers
> or objects associated with it. A gerund is a noun made from a verb
> root plus ing (a present participle). A whole gerund phrase functions
> in a sentence just like a noun, and can act as a subject, an object,
> or a predicate nominative.

Bear in mind: some gerunds (get, getting, drop, dropping, leave, leaving, please, pleasing) call for doubling the final consonant or dropping a final vowel before the ing.

[gerund phrases](https://A%20whole%20gerund%20phrase%20functions%20in%20a%20sentence%20just%20like%20a%20noun,%20and%20can%20act%20as%20a%20subject,%20an%20object,%20or%20a%20predicate%20nominative.)

Comment: @BillJ There is absolutely nothing in it that is nonsense **based on the way** the OP asked his question. You are just angry because of how I explained how to get a gerund from an infinitive. Tsk tsk tsk.

Comment: Not angry at all. You don't understand conversion, do you? Go look it up.

Comment: You are clueless about how to talk to ELLers, aren't you? "Yes, nouns can be formed from the ing form of verbs, as in "I witnessed the killing of the seals". Read what you said! It is materially off: Nouns can be the ing form of verbs. NOT FORMED. The ING form of the damn verb is ALREADY a noun,

Comment: It is you that is clueless about grammar. The _ing_ form of a verb is not already a noun. In "He was expelled for killing the birds", "killing" is a verb. But in "He witnessed the killing of the birds", "killing" is a noun formed by **conversion** from the gerund-participle verb "killing", not from the base form "kill". Elementary stuff. End of.

Comment: @BillJ It is already a noun in the dictionary. Of course, not in an utterance or sentence! What you are "converting" is the function it serves in a sentence: That's what makes it a noun or verb.